# Finding the coefficients of the block diagram

Tags: filter-design, digital-filters

I was looking at the question from a textbook of mine and it doesn't make too much sense to me:

> Design a ﬁrst-order ﬁlter, linearly extrapolating the current and
> previous measurement. This is equivalent to the assumption that the
> upcoming measurement will be on a straight line connecting the current
> and previous measurement. The output of the ﬁlter shall anticipate
> this by giving this output now.

The coefficients (2 and -1) are given in the answer, but I still don't understand how they were found.

I know that the general equation of a digital filter is given as:

\begin{equation}
    y[k] = \sum_{i=0}^{N} b_i u[k-i] - \sum_{j=1}^{N} a_i y[k-j]
\end{equation}

How does one go from that, using the description of the problem, to:

\begin{equation}
    y[k] = 2 x[k] - x[k-1]
\end{equation}

This is the answer given in the book:

> [image]

Comment: Hint : think about y = m*x+b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, there are 2 parts to this problem

Step 1 :

Find the slope between the last 2 samples. The slope is simply the difference between the last 2 samples.

$$ m = x[n]-x[n-1]; $$

Step 2 :

You need to extrapolate to find the next sample based on the hypothesis that the next sample will be colinear with the 2 previous samples.

$ x[n+1] = x[n] + m $

$ x[n+1] = x[n] + x[n] - x[n-1] = 2x[n] - x[n-1]$

Answer (score 2):

If you assume that the samples lie on a line then the current sample is related to the previous sample by

$$x[n]=x[n-1]+c\tag{1}$$

with some unknown constant $c$. If there are two past samples given, then $c$ is simply determined by the difference between these two samples:

$$c= x[n-1]-x[n-2]\tag{2}$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives

$$x[n]=2x[n-1]-x[n-2]\tag{3}$$

Comment: you beat me to it. I will delete my answer!

Comment: @Ben: same thought at the same time :)